# Is there a way to make a tcp-layer proxy faster?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-sockets

I need a proxy that can recieve TCP packets from a client and forward it to a server and vice versa. A basic implementation to transact an email works but it takes substantially more time than a non-proxied implementation (~9s vs ~25s). I'm not sure how I should choose my settimeout since that seems to be the bottleneck.

Here's the basic code:

```
import socket

MSG_SIZE = 64000 # max size of a tcp packet
SRV_ADDR = "server-address"
SRV_PORT = 587
HOST_ADDR = "localhost"
HOST_PORT = 5000

res_counter = 0

# set up host socket
host_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host_conn.bind((HOST_ADDR, HOST_PORT))

while True:
    # Wait for client connection.
    try:
        host_conn.listen() 
        client_conn, addr = host_conn.accept()  # Establish connection with client.
        srv_conn = socket.create_connection((SRV_ADDR, SRV_PORT))
        client_conn.settimeout(0.6)
        srv_conn.settimeout(0.6)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", e)
        continue

while res_counter <= 2:
    client_data = None
    srv_data = None

    try:
        client_data = client_conn.recv(MSG_SIZE)
        while client_data:
            client_data += client_conn.recv(MSG_SIZE)

    except socket.timeout:
        if client_data:
            srv_conn.sendall(client_data)
       

    try:
        srv_data = srv_conn.recv(MSG_SIZE)
        while srv_data:
            srv_data += srv_conn.recv(MSG_SIZE)

    except socket.timeout:
        if srv_data:
            client_conn.sendall(srv_data)


    
    if not client_data and not srv_data:
        res_counter += 1
```